# document.write different from console.log?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this neat library (https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES) to encrypt my messages.

From the following example AES example:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<script>
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
</script>
```

When I ***document.write(encrypted)*** it returns:

**"U2FsdGVkX18W1n0wES5YsBzpRoRB1iu2KqzQiUSe6zE="**

Which is what I want. But when I ***console.log(encrypted)*** it returns:

---

> { init: [Function],   '$super':     { init: [Function],
>        toString: [Function],
>        '$super': 
>         { extend: [Function],
>           create: [Function],
>           init: [Function],
>           mixIn: [Function],
>           clone: [Function] } },   ciphertext:     { words: 
>         [ -463593157,
>           -130193625,
>           475395301,
>           1812962665,
>           -1322700187,
>           433662359,
>           1675036770,
>           -337777864 ],
>        sigBytes: 32 },   key:     { init: [Function],
>        '$super': 
>         { init: [Function],
>           toString: [Function],
>           concat: [Function],
>           clamp: [Function],
>           clone: [Function],
>           random: [Function],
>           '$super': [Object] },
>        words: 
>         [ -1836471768,
>           609934685,
>           -835470701,
>           413762839,
>           1279413942,
>           -1961507681,
>           -1590403020,
>           392722880,
>           2059661770,
>           1403440185,
>           1364381326,
>           1252361221 ],
>        sigBytes: 32 },   iv:     { init: [Function],
>        '$super': 
>         { init: [Function],
>           toString: [Function],
>           concat: [Function],
>           clamp: [Function],
>           clone: [Function],
>           random: [Function],
>           '$super': [Object] },
>        words: [ 2059661770, 1403440185, 1364381326, 1252361221 ],
>        sigBytes: 16 },   algorithm:     { _doReset: [Function],
>        encryptBlock: [Function],
>        decryptBlock: [Function],
>        _doCryptBlock: [Function],
>        keySize: 8,
>        init: [Function],
>        '$super': 
>         { cfg: [Object],
>           reset: [Function],
>           _doProcessBlock: [Function],
>           _doFinalize: [Function],
>           blockSize: 4,
>           init: [Function],
>           '$super': [Object] } },   mode:     { init: [Function],
>        '$super': 
>         { createEncryptor: [Function],
>           createDecryptor: [Function],
>           init: [Function],
>           '$super': [Object] },
>        Encryptor: 
>         { processBlock: [Function],
>           init: [Function],
>           '$super': [Circular] },
>        Decryptor: 
>         { processBlock: [Function],
>           init: [Function],
>           '$super': [Circular] } },   padding: { pad: [Function], unpad: [Function] },   blockSize: 4,   formatter: { stringify: [Function],
>   parse: [Function] },   salt: { words: [ 359292117, -310439037 ],
>   sigBytes: 8 } }

---

Why do both methods return different results and how to I make ***console.log*** behave like ***document.write***?

Comment: console.log(encrypted.toString()); ?

Comment: Yeah Eric, I figured it out already. But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out it's as simple as **console.log(encrypted.toString());**